# recycler view items weird behavior

Tags: android

I have used a `recycler` view to display my list of songs.

So, every song comes up as a `cardview` which contains two `textviews`.

Now everything is perfect untill i tried setting the `boldface` to the selected item.

```
View view= mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(currID);
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(currID);// This works fine.
final TextView textView=view.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Now this does work but what i can see is that every 12th item got this typeface even though i specified the id of the item.

Like suppose, if i add this code `Log.e("Value",textView.getText().toString());` to the above lines it gives me the corresponding item textview value.

Why the `boldface` is getting set to every  12th value inside the recyclerview.

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Update**
[MyAdapterCode](https://pastebin.com/0ZAu5Qs4)

Comment: since the same view item is recycled, just the text value changed. the textview style stay intact. you need to reset the typeface when view recycled/reused

Comment: Just put the typeface bold in xml editor.

Comment: @hakim how do i do that part?

Comment: @DexSebas uhuhh? i want the selected item to be bold and when it's not selected , remove that bold face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let your adapter handle that setting, not you directly reaching inside the recycler view.

You data structure should have a property that you set to be selected, and then you call adapter [notifyItemChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))

And you adapter should have something like

```
onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder..) {
   if (song.isSelected()) {
       // set bold
   } else {
      // set regular
   }
}
```

In your Song class, you need to add a boolean property if that song should be in bold or not.

And call to your adapter with ID or position, update the song, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged()`

**EDIT**

You need to remove your code that sets the bold style from Activity/Fragment and put it in your onBindViewHolder

You selected property needs to be part of your song object not the ViewHolder.

At the place where you get your broadcast, you need to update the Song object in the list inside your adapter and call one of the notifyXxx methods.

Comment: i have two textboxes , how do i put a checkable property? checkbox?

Comment: No, put it in your model, in the adapter, post your adapter code, i'll be able to help you better

Comment: i did what you told me to do, but that doesn;t help either , same thing happens , plus i have updated the question

Comment: `public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position,List<Object> payloads) {
        if(!payloads.isEmpty()) {
            if (payloads.get(0) instanceof ArrayList) {
               if((long)((ArrayList) payloads.get(0)).get(0) ==list.get(position).getId()) {
                   holder.textViewTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
               }else holder.textViewTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        }else {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder,position, payloads);
        }
    }`

Comment: i think what i want is a sort of event which lets me know when a certain view is getting recycled or reused

Comment: Give me your fragment as the adapter where you now set the bold

Comment: wait.. i think what you are trying to sayyy :) , i am gonna implement it

Answer (score 0):

Because it's recyclerview and doesn't create each time new items but reuses on scroll. So you need to set normal typeface by default

```
textView.setTypeface(null,selected ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Comment: how do i set the selected?

Comment: @BOTJr. how currently you detect selected row?

Comment: i have a broad cast receiver that gets fired when the song is prepared to be loaded, in the intent of that receiver i can get the id of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Try set normal typeFace before every new item's position, so it will prevent 12th item got unwanted typeface.

```
   onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder..) {
   //set normal before every new item's position
   textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
   if (song.isSelected()) {
       // set bold
   } else {
      // set normal
       }
   }
```

Comment: Add context o we can learn from it; or bots will remove it due to lack of it. Answer is/was flagged for deletion. Flag this answer for deletion after you updated your answer.